# How to correctly interrupt boost::asio::read on a boost::asio::serial_port under Linux?

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

The code is very straitforward, just opening a socket, starting a synchronous read thread and trying to stop it.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void readThread(boost::asio::serial_port* port)
{
    static const size_t maxBytesToRead = 256;
    unsigned char buffer[maxBytesToRead];
    size_t read = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            std::cout << "readThread reading" << std::endl;
            read = boost::asio::read(*port,
                        boost::asio::buffer(buffer, maxBytesToRead));
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cout << "exception in readThread, about to stop" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    boost::asio::serial_port port(service);

    //port.open("/dev/ttyACM0");
    port.open("COM9");
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(115200));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::none));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size(8));
    port.set_option(
            boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(
                boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::hardware));

    std::thread thrd(&readThread, &port);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

    std::cout << "Calling cancel()" << std::endl; 
    port.cancel();
    std::cout << "Called cancel()" << std::endl;

    thrd.join();

    std::cout << "Exiting, OK" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This works perfectly fine under Windows, and outputs:

```
readThread reading
Calling cancel()
Called cancel()
exception in readThread, about to stop
Exiting, OK
```

But, under Linux, the read operation in thread does not get interrupted, output is:

```
readThread reading
Calling cancel()
Called cancel()
```

and then the application hangs forever.

What's the right strategy to interrupt this synchronous read? I'd like not to move to async read as I'm porting the app to Linux and wish to do miniam changes in the code structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancellation requires async read. You used a non-portable undocumented effect for `serial_port::cancel` on windows.

What's worse, calling `cancel` on the port is a data race, so you have [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as well.

Instead of a thread, make that an async read chain:

```
using read_state = std::array<unsigned char, 256>;

void readThread(asio::serial_port& port, std::shared_ptr<read_state> state = {}) {
    if (!state) {
        state = std::make_shared<read_state>(); // shared for the entire async chain
    }
    async_read(port, asio::buffer(*state),
               [&port, state](error_code ec, size_t bytes_read) {
                   std::cout << "received " << bytes_read << " (" << ec.message() << ")"
                             << std::endl;
                   if (!ec) {
                       readThread(port, state);
                   }
               });
}
```

Now you can rewrite `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    asio::io_service service;
    using asio::serial_port;
    serial_port port(service, argc > 1 ? argv[1] : default_device);

    port.set_option(serial_port::baud_rate(115200));
    port.set_option(serial_port::parity(serial_port::parity::none));
    port.set_option(serial_port::stop_bits(serial_port::stop_bits::one));
    port.set_option(serial_port::character_size(8));
    port.set_option(serial_port::flow_control(serial_port::flow_control::hardware));

    readThread(port);

    // preferrably with a timer, or on Ctrl-C
    std::thread([&port] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

        std::cout << "Calling cancel()" << std::endl;
        post(port.get_executor(), [&] { port.cancel(); });
        std::cout << "Called cancel()" << std::endl;
    }).detach();

    service.run();

    std::cout << "Exited, OK" << std::endl;
}
```

Or, by using a thread pool, avoid the manual thread:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    asio::thread_pool service(1);
    using asio::serial_port;
    serial_port port(make_strand(service), argc > 1 ? argv[1] : default_device);

    port.set_option(serial_port::baud_rate(115200));
    port.set_option(serial_port::parity(serial_port::parity::none));
    port.set_option(serial_port::stop_bits(serial_port::stop_bits::one));
    port.set_option(serial_port::character_size(8));
    port.set_option(serial_port::flow_control(serial_port::flow_control::hardware));

    readThread(port);

    // preferrably with a timer, or on Ctrl-C
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    std::cout << "Calling cancel()" << std::endl;
    post(port.get_executor(), [&] { port.cancel(); });
    std::cout << "Called cancel()" << std::endl;

    service.join();

    std::cout << "Exited, OK" << std::endl;
}
```

### Several Improvements + Demo

Suggesting to e.g. exit on a timer or signal instead of from a background thread, adding some tracing and a live demo:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c81a294ec375dc73)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

static auto const  start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
static inline void trace(auto const&... args) {
    std::cout << std::setw(8) << (std::chrono::steady_clock::now()-start)/1ms << "ms ";
    (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
}

#ifdef _WIN32
    auto constexpr static default_device = "COM9";
#else
    auto constexpr static default_device = "/dev/ttyACM0";
#endif

struct read_state {
    std::array<unsigned char, 256> buffer;
    size_t                         total_bytes = 0;
};

void readThread(asio::serial_port& port, std::shared_ptr<read_state> s = {}) {
    if (!s) {
        s = std::make_shared<read_state>(); // shared for the entire async chain
    }
    //port.async_read_some(
    async_read(port, //
               asio::buffer(s->buffer), [&port, s](error_code ec, size_t bytes_read) {
                   s->total_bytes += bytes_read;
                   trace("received ", bytes_read, "/", s->total_bytes / 1024.0 / 1024,
                         "Mb (", ec.message(), ")");

                   if (!ec) {
                       readThread(port, s); // continue reading
                   }
               });
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed;

    asio::thread_pool service;
    auto strand = make_strand(service);

    using asio::serial_port;
    serial_port port(strand, argc > 1 ? argv[1] : default_device);

    asio::signal_set sig(service, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    sig.async_wait([&](error_code ec, int num) {
        trace("signal ", num, "(", ec.message(), ")");
        if (!ec) {
            post(strand, [&] { port.close(); });
            trace("cancelled");
        }
    });

    port.set_option(serial_port::baud_rate(115200));
    port.set_option(serial_port::parity(serial_port::parity::none));
    port.set_option(serial_port::stop_bits(serial_port::stop_bits::one));
    port.set_option(serial_port::character_size(8));
    port.set_option(serial_port::flow_control(serial_port::flow_control::hardware));

    readThread(port);

    service.join();

    trace("Exited, OK");
}
```

[image]

### CAVEAT

Note the subtlety that I used `port.close()` in that last example instead of `port.cancel()`. Using `cancel()` risked a race condition where the read thread will not exit when there the `cancel()` arrives at the exact time that there is no async read in flight (instead the completion handler is pending).

If you prefer `cancel()` for purity, you will need additional state, like a `cancelled` flag, like so: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65ee6e46755cdbeb)**. Notice how sometimes the last read ends with `(Success)` and sometimes with `(Operation canceled)`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a66bi.jpg

Another option might be to use [`asio::cancellation_slot`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/cancellation_slot.html)

Comment: Added a caveat on the risk of race condition (which is different from a data race) when using `cancel`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first versions you propose and it works fine under Windows at least. (will test Linux)  Actually it still calls `port.cancel()`, what's the difference with my original code actually? Just the fact that you used `async_read` rather than `read`?

Comment: First problem I see is that `boost::asio::read` with a buffer of 256 returns as soon as we received some data. Your code only only reads blocks of 256 bytes, so if the device sent 10 bytes for instance, we won't see the "received 10 bytes" message untill cancel is called.

Comment: First comment: yes.

Comment: Second comment: that's not true. I specifically have the commented line with `port.async_read_some` which **does** have the semantics that you describe. See [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html#:~:text=The%20asynchronous%20operation%20will%20continue%20until%20one%20of%20the%20following%20conditions%20is%20true): _"The asynchronous operation will continue until one of the following conditions is true: 1. The supplied buffers are full. That is, the bytes transferred is equal to the sum of the buffer sizes.
2. An error occurred."_

Comment: Just use the call you need, but I obviously stuck with the code from the question, because that was your code. (I should have linked the docs for [`read`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload1.html) but the semantics are the same)

Comment: For completeness, I [edited the example to use `async_read_some`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76c205c27982e743) as I had already hinted in the commented-out line of code, and also using `cancellation_slot`, even though that is unrelated and really serves no purpose for this example: https://imgur.com/a/qtHkt8E - you can see how the shorter messages arrive immediately (subject to your sender/OS buffering)

Comment: By the way, if you claim that "boost::asio::read with a buffer of 256 returns as soon as we received some data" on windows then that is a bug reportable here: https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues

Comment: A combination of `port.async_read_some` interrupted by a `port.close` worked like a charm. Thank you sehe.